# how to get post data in joomla Version 3.x

Tags: php, post, joomla, http-post, postdata

Try to get data with 1POST` in joomla :

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$catid =  $jinput->post->getint('catid', 0);
```

but it always return `0`
also when i try :

```
$catid = $jinput->getint('catid',0);
```

it works to receive with `GET` But not works with `POST`

How to fix it to works out with `POST` ?

Comment: Check this http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/55/whats-the-proper-way-to-get-the-entire-post

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma checked before create this post, not works

Comment: `getint` ahould be `getInt`. Case sensitive.

Comment: It Dosn't Work with `getInt`